# Sorting through MySQL sort of

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, here is my basic data structure of my DB...at least the parts of it that I need to worry about and work with...

```
id       
address    
city          
state        
zipcode      (5 digit zip, looked up via usps by address)
realtor_id   (unique id for the realtor)
type_of_work
```

When an order is put into the website and want a sign put up, they order an installation, most of the time, the address is put in like "1550 Libby Street", a lot of the time, they don't put in the last part, "avenue, street, road, court, etc" so they aren't always entered the same way.

When an order is put into the website and want a sign taken down, they order a removal, they often don't put the address in the same way, this time, they might put the address in like, "1550 Libby St".

Right now, each and every order comes in, is a separate insert into the DB.

What I would like to figure out how to do, is when an order comes in for an installation, insert into DB, if a removal comes in for the same address, update the original insert.

I am trying to set it up so that I can search through the DB and find addresses that have been installed but not removed yet so that I can display them on a map.  If I can keep the DB the way it is, and be able to find addresses that have been installed and not removed yet, then that would work too.  Does that make sense?

I attempted to find an answer that was already posted, but not sure how to phrase the question or ask it.  Sorry if it has already been posted.

Comment: Welcome. To ask On Topic question, please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I understand your problem, but I do not really understand what you would like us to help you with. Based on the current format of the question it seems to me that you would like us to write code that displays addresses on a map from your db and then ve able to update the records. This is a very broad question, since you have not provided any code.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a few separate issues here:

### Inconsistent address names

This is going to be hard to solve without just convincing your clients to enter the address properly every time. Giving them separate fields (address lines 1/2, city, state, zip) will help, since it will prompt them to enter the entire address.

Alternatively, you might want to let them see all of the jobs they've had installed, and then pick which ones need removal. If they never enter the address twice, then they can't get it wrong!

### Removals after installations

You shouldn't overwrite the record for a client at a particular address when they decide to have a sign removed. What if they cancel the removal? What if they want another sign installed there, and you now don't know that you've already worked on that site before?

Instead, you should be inserting a new row into the database for each event.

### Finding installations that haven't been removed yet

It's a bit unclear what `id` is - does this uniquely identify every single row, or does each job have its own `id`?

I'll go ahead and assume each job has its own `id`.

Since MySQL can't do `EXCEPT`, you'll need to do a `WHERE NOT IN` query instead:

`SELECT
  signs.id, signs.address
FROM
  signs
WHERE
  signs.type_of_work = 'INSTALLATION'
  AND
  signs.id NOT IN
    (
    SELECT signs2.id FROM signs2 WHERE signs2.type_of_work = 'REMOVAL'
    )`

(pardon my style; I'm more used to Postgres...)

This should select the id and address of every job hat has installation work, *unless* that job's `id` is associated with removal work.

Comment: I understand the Inconsistent address names, I have tried to get them to use the correct address every time, also added an address lookup, but then the users get lost and don't always understand what is going on. The address lookup used to be a required, but so many users got stuck and started calling that I had to just make it available and not required. There are separate lines for the address, city, state, etc. As it stands, right now, when an install or removal comes in, every order is a new line in the DB. No lines are removed or deleted.  "id" is the unique identifier used.

Comment: Yes, I have also thought about just having the users select the previously entered addresses for removals, the only problem with that is, I built the DB after the business was started, a ton of the installs and removal list is in Google Sheets and I would have to manually enter all of that information into the DB and hope that it would keep track perfectly.

Comment: It sounds like this is more of a UX (user experience) problem than something that you can really solve with the database alone. If you could show the users a list of jobs of each type (ordered, installed, slated for removal, removal), then it'd be a lot easier for everyone involved.

Comment: the addresses are mostly the same, usually they have the first part of the address alike "1550 libby"  and "1550 Libby Street", if i could find addresses that only had the installation and not the removal where the address is similar?  Or should I just try for a new UX and attempt to get it to work they way I would like?  Probably poor planning on my end...looking like epic failure, again!  YAY!

Comment: Since you do not want to redesign I will try to offer a temporary solution. You could strip out all of the different ways they write "street" or "road".  So if column a="123 st." And b="123 street"  then REPLACE(REPLACE(a,"st",'""),"street",''") will equal REPLACE(REPLACE(b,"st",'""),"street",''").  Not the best idea, but like I said, a temporary solution while redesigning.

Comment: @Bleach thanks for the idea, I will see if that will work for me!  I wouldn't mind redesigning, just not too sure where to begin.  If I make slow changes, it shouldn't scare the users, they are easily frightened and resist change!

Comment: Could it possibly work like this?  Array1 = Installations, Array2 = Removals, compare Array1 and Array 2, to see if addresses are same or similar, then put results into Array3?

Comment: @Bleach Any possible suggestions on how I should redesign the database?